# citrix blocking ext library xpages

Tags: xpages, citrix-access-gateway

I'm in the process of deploying an xpages 8.5.3 app which users the xpages ext library.

Internally the app is working great, but for our ipad users to access it they need to go through a citrix gateway. It appears that the gateway is not allowing a couple of the files through. We are getting and error.

Could not load 'extlib.dijit.DynamicContent'

The network guys have found details that indicate it might be the way that the path's are defined in the Java script some use () and other use [].  I need to know which one you use in domino to access the built in ext script libraries. Does anyone know?

http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX122319

Thanks

Comment: Hi, I'm interested in the issue you reported.  I have found that people from a specific company (using Citrix) keep finding that IE or Chrome both crash when they try to use an xpages site I have created.  Did you find that it was crashing or were they getting this error message?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I ended up publishing the application as an App instead of a website. It was a change in how the app is deployed but it seemed to work. I know, not the answer you were looking for... If you do find an answer I am very interested in hearing it.

Comment: Thanks Pat, I'll let you know if I come up with something.